# How to get innerHTML of XML tag has specific id attribute using php?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, attributes

Having a xml file, how i can get content with/without attribute? For example having something as:

```
<book id="1">
  <title>...</title>
  <author>...</author>
</book>
<book id="2">
  <title>...</title>
  <author>...</author>
</book>
<book id="3">
  <title>...</title>
  <author>...</author>
</book>
```

Giving to input tagname as `book` and `id` as `2`, it should return all which inside it, in this case:

```
<title>...</title>
<author>...</author>
```

I have solved problem looking xml file as a string and working with the string but i want ask is possible to do some using a xml-file without scroll directly all content. 
In real i have big xml file (something as 30-40 MB) and simply want search a content in it giving as coordinates tag-name and (if present) the attribute/s.
The structure of file not is a "constant".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DOMXPath::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) is a good method to filter selected elements by `XPath`. You can select elements has specific attribute. The code find `book` tag that value of `id` attribute of it is `2`.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($str);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$book = $xpath->query("//book[@id='2']")->item(0);

foreach($book->childNodes as $node) {
   @$html .= $dom->saveHTML($node);
}
echo $html;
```

Note that the final part of code loop through childs of selected element to get html of them.

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/XCDfF)